# git: Merge two branches with secret files in one branch

Tags: git, merge

I'd like to keep two branches for some tutorials, one branch `S` with some "secret" corrected files, and one public branch `P` with the same files, but not yet corrected (only a skeleton). The idea would then to push only the `P` branch on a public repo, and keep both branches on my private repo. And of course, because the two branches are quite similar, I'd like to make sure I can merge changes from branch `S` on branch `P`.

So for now I have my secret branch `S`, and I create an orphan branch `P`. I create then a commit containing all the files that branch `P` should contain. But when I modify branch `S` and try to merge  this change with branch `P` (with `--allow-unrelated-histories`), then all commits of branch `S` appear also on branch `P` history... so everybody can read the secret corrected files !

I tried to use `merge --squash` instead, and the history of branch `S` are not copied into `P`, but now the problem is that the two branches stay unrelated, and as a consequence git cannot really solve any merge conflicts because it can't find a "common ancestor" between the two branches.

Any idea how I could solve that issue?

Thanks!

-- EDIT --

After thinking a bit, I think that I would need a feature that just push all the commits of the current branch, but that does not push the commits of the merged branch. Is it possible ?

Comment: No, you can't get what you want from Git. You can get sort of close using cherry-pick, but it will be pretty manual and painful/

Comment: @torek : Ok thanks... That's too bad...